# Javascript only loads when I refresh the page in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a widget I'm using from a software provider (Mindbody) it has a script tag to load a purchase widget you can embed into your webpage. I'm using create-react-app to create a simple page with a modal and the button of the link but for some reason the page doesn't load on initial visit. You have to refresh the page and then the page will load. Any guidance? Is there a function I can call that initiates the javscript once the window is loaded for react?

- I should also note a I am using react-router-dom to route to the web page that won't load until refresh

  ```
    const Widget = () => {
  return(
   <div>
    <healcode-widget data-version="0.2" data-link-class="healcode-pricing-option- 
     text-link" data-site-id="30089" data-mb-site-id="686934" data-bw-identity- 
     site="false" data-type="pricing-link" data-inner-html="Purchase now" data- 
     service-id="101165" />
   </div>
  )
  ```

  }

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
      Widget();
    }, []);
  ```

Routing to this page

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { Stack, Box, Typography, Modal, Backdrop } from '@mui/material';
import ButtonV2 from './ButtonV2';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  boxShadow: 24,
  borderRadius: 3,
  transition: "5s ease-in-out"
};

const PurchaseLanding = () => {

    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);


  return (
    <div>
        <Modal
        open={show}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        disableAutoFocus="true" 
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}>
            
        <Box sx={style}>
            <div>
                {/* full width image */}
            <img style={{borderRadius: "10px 10px 0 0"}} src="https://res.cloudinary.com/djjb1vyjm/image/upload/v1660541084/1_uxhi8p.png" width="100%" alt="" />
            </div>
            <Box p={2}>
                {/* title */}
            <Typography align="center" id="modal-modal-title" variant="h5" component="h2">
            <span className='space-font-heavy'>Buy your [10-pack]</span>
            </Typography>

            {/*  onboarding message */}
            <Stack pb={3} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" direction="row" spacing={2}>
                <Typography px={1} align="center" id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                    <span className='space-font-light'>Once completed download the Mindbody app to add, update, and book your workouts!</span>
                </Typography>
            </Stack>

            {/* button group left/right */}
            
            <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
              <Link m={2} className='button-27'><div className='links'><healcode-widget data-version="0.2" data-link-class="healcode-pricing-option-text-link" data-site-id="30089" data-mb-site-id="686934" data-bw-identity-site="false" data-type="pricing-link" data-inner-html="Purchase now" data-service-id="101165" /></div></Link>

            </Stack>

            </Box>
        </Box>
        </Modal>

    </div>
  );
}


export default PurchaseLanding
```

Comment: where are you routing? Can you share the code snippet too?

Comment: Meanwhile calling this `Widget()` inside an `useEffect` is not valid React approach of doing things, since from what I see,  `Widget` is a React component.

Comment: Just updated my page that is being routed to. Ok ignore the useEffect, it's actually doing nothing. I put the component in the modal content which is where is should show. It's basically a link to a purchase page. When I delete it loads, when i add it back it doesn't load

Comment: You can add widget in index.html page under public folder.

Comment: My page still doesn't load when I add this component as it's own file. I need to refresh, I think it has to do with react-router-dom and being routing to a page with script tag in it, it loads fine when i remove the <healcode-widget /> tag

Comment: Or another work around would be how to refresh the page once when the page is loaded. I see window.location.reload() but this will reload infinite which I want just once